# How JQuery assign function name to $?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know 
How JQuery assign function name to $ ?

Comment: Well, it is open source, maybe you can go and take a look. But as Quenting said, I doubt that it's anything special.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is done at line `9384` of the uncompressed library (see http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js)

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

where `jQuery` on the right side of this assignment is the function-scoped reference (starting at line `22`): of course you could create your favourite shortcut (e.g. `_`) doing something like

```
window._ = window.jQuery
```

after you've loaded the library, so you can use `_` instead of `$` or `jQuery`.

If you asked this because you have loaded some other libraries and you have a conflict with the `$` reference, just take a look at [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) method

Answer (score 5):

The same way as they assign a function to any other variable name. There is nothing special about the `$` character in function names.

The specific way that jQuery use can be found [in their source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L370)

```
window.$ = _$;
```

Comment: Maybe, he's if it does so through the use of an anonymous function, or just with `function $()`...

Answer (score 0):

I think they simply do

```
window.$ = jQuery;
```

to be more precise, they first save $

```
var jQuery = (function() {

// Define a local copy of jQuery
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
},

// Map over jQuery in case of overwrite
_jQuery = window.jQuery,

// Map over the $ in case of overwrite
_$ = window.$,
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be just a normal assignment in the global scope.

```
$ = Jquery;
```

There ought to be some safety checks to make sure $ has not been defined already.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to this:

```
window.$ = function() {
    alert('Hello world!');
}

$();
```

There is nothing special about `$` in JavaScript function names. This is also acceptable:

```
function $() {
    alert('Hello world!');
}
```